# Убрать отступы вокруг треугольника у spinner android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это spinner. Текст не умещается при такой ширине. Если увеличить ширину то текст поместиться. Видимо у треугольника имеются отступы слева. Можно ли их как-то убрать? И как это сделать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45845453/android-spinner-remove-extra-white-space-between-text-and-dropdown-icon

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему указав padding справа 16dp. Если не указывать видимо padding намного больше